# How do I control the timeout of an Device Code Authentication Flow using MSAL/Python against Azure AD?

Tags: python, azure-ad-msal, azure-authentication

**Background:**
I am running a browserless application in python using the device code flow to authenticate with Azure Active Directory with token caching using the Python Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL).  I wrote the script based on [this blog post](https://keathmilligan.net/automate-your-work-with-msgraph-and-python).  I intend to run this script on a cron job every day, **but would like to reduce the time that the [`msal.acquire_token_by_device_flow()`](https://msal-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#msal.PublicClientApplication.acquire_token_by_device_flow) method waits to receive the token** after successful authentication in browser.  It appears the default value is about 5 hours.  This specific use case is when the 90 day refresh token expires and the user needs to re-authenticate, I'd like the script to not hang for hours waiting for the user to reauthenticate.

**What I've Tried:**
I tried to control this by using the inherited `timeout` argument (in seconds) when instantiating the [`PublicClientApplication()`](https://msal-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#msal.ClientApplication) object, but it did not affect the timeout.  I am not using the `http_client` argument (mentioned when using `timeout`).  Specifically, I have tried both of the following instantiations:

```
app = msal.PublicClientApplication(client_id = CLIENT_ID, authority=AUTHORITY, token_cache=cache, timeout=60)
```

and

```
app = msal.PublicClientApplication(client_id = CLIENT_ID, authority=AUTHORITY, token_cache=cache, timeout=(60,60))
```

Neither of these affect the timeout I'm looking for.  After about 5 hours, the response back from the `msal.acquire_token_by_device_flow()` if I don't authenticate is: [image]

I appreciate any help, or even a response to know if what I want to do is possible to control in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to abort the polling loop at any time, we can change the value of the flow’s “expires_at” key. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/msal/msal.application.publicclientapplication?view=azure-python#acquire-token-by-device-flow-flow--claims-challenge-none----kwargs-)

For example

```
import requests
import msal
from datetime import datetime
import time
import json
app = msal.PublicClientApplication(client_id='',
                                   authority='')

flow = app.initiate_device_flow(scopes=["User.Read"])

if "user_code" not in flow:
    raise ValueError(
        "Fail to create device flow. Err: %s" % json.dumps(flow, indent=4))
flow['expires_at'] = int(time.time())+20
print(flow["message"])

print(datetime.now())
result = app.acquire_token_by_device_flow(flow)

if "access_token" not in result:
    print(datetime.now())
    print(result)
```

[image]

Comment: Just confirmed your solution works on my end.  I was looking in the wrong place..  needed to look at the flow object.  Thanks, Jim!